# MySQL frustrating me -

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code, it is based on [WORKING example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-proftpd-with-a-mysql-backend-on-ubuntu-12-10) (just less rows and character/varchar is changed on few of them)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniqueid` character(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `example1` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `example2` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `example3` bit(2) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `example4` bit(2) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `example5` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `example6` character(39) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `example7` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `example8` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `example9` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `example0` int(10) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  `accessed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci COMMENT='Basic user handling';
```

I tryed with mySQL million times, and it always frustrate me again and again:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' `accessed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01', `modified` date' at line 13
```

Unfortunately, that's not only error....

When I fix one (remove field) - another appears!

I was though it's my server, since I migrated recently to MariaDB, but I tested with http://sqlfiddle.com/

And same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`example0` int(10) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT,
                                                           ^-- ?!
```

If you're going to use the `DEFAULT` keyword here, you need a valid value following it.

Generally speaking, MySQL syntax errors show up on the first word that the parser can't figure out. If you aren't sure what's causing the error, look at what comes **before** the words it's complaining about.

Comment: I can't believe, but it works! After spent more than hour trying to figure out useless MySQL messages and it's weird way, just minor change in one line fixed everything up. Thank you!
Now I also know how to read weird MySQL error format.